# Is there an universal way to get the help for a command in cmd?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, help-files

I have noticed there are multiple ways to get help information within the Windows command line (cmd) using the `help`, `?`, `/?` tokens.

For example, these are valid:

```
help tasklist
help find
tasklist /?
netstat ?
netstat \?
netstat /?
find /?
```

These are not valid:

```
help netstat
tasklist ?
tasklist \?
find ?
```

It seems a bit unpredictable.

1. **As asked in the title, is there an universal token/keyword to pull
   the help for a cmd command?**
2. *Bonus question. Is there perhaps a way of knowing which command works with which token?*

Comment: I just use [An A-Z Index of Windows CMD commands - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/) and go from there to look at the full entry for a particular command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Is there an universal token/keyword to pull the help for a cmd command?**
>
> Short answer. No.

### help token

The `help` "token" is actually calling the `help.exe` utility stored in C:\Windows\System32\help.exe. If you type `help` or `help.exe` within CMD, you will be able to see all the commands that the help utility knows about.

Luckily if you run help + any command, it should tell you what to type to get the help. Often, you will need to type /?.

---

### ? token

As for the `?` token, it will not work with commands that expect a text argument as the `?` will be interpreted literally and not as an option. Commands such as find, findstr, replace, mkdir and other will not show help if passed `?`. Specify the `?` is an option using `/?` to show the help for commands expecting text arguments.

Until proven wrong, I believe you can safely assume that that if an utility does not appear on the help list `cmd /k help`, you should use /? to get its help.